# how to connect two user after login to my flutter account?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am an intermediate flutter developer and I am working on a chat app. I did google signup and is working fine, but I don't have any idea about this app. like how to connect two users. It's okay if they can get connected after sharing a link on WhatsApp can someone guide me Step By Step?Thanks in advance

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Please share more details on how you're integrating chat functionality

Answer (score 0):

I refereed to this YouTube channel when I was making a chat app during my flutter training. You could refer to it to understand the fundamentals for creating a chat app.

Hope this helps!

Link: https://youtu.be/FTju8w4zEno